# How to detect event in console by using java

Tags: java, events, terminal

I am trying to write a litte editor which  looks like nano or vi . 
But For the moment , I have difficulties to directly detect events in the terminal . 
Does someone know how i can do ? 
thanks

ps : I want to do that by just using native java , no additional library

Comment: What kind of events? Keyboard events?

Comment: Java console IO is not event based; afaik you can't do it without an additional library.

Comment: I dont really get your question. If you want to send Arguments to your console you most likly use `String[] args`. You can run your code with the specified arguments. To pass events you would need another libary.

Comment: @CraigOtis : Yes keybord events . 
Basically I want to define some actions if the user push some  buttons combinations . For exemple Ctrl-S to save , Ctrl-o to select the next word ...

Comment: The terminal isn't going to give you these events - it buffers input and sends it to the program after the enter key (normally) is pressed. If you want to create your own console-*like* application in Java, you'd probably need to spool up your own UI, or use some third-party library. I'm not familiar with any, though.